# Async-Await functionality response became undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

Iam trying to pass URL to async function and later taking its response and trying to use its value, but here response get undefined and await not waiting until value available. what is the reason for this and how can solve this

```javascript
const AuthForm = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [signupError, setSignupError] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const switchAuthModeHandler = () => {
    setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
  };
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = emailRef.current.value;
    const password = emailRef.current.value;
    const dbconnect = async (URL) => {
      fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: false,
        }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) return res;
          else throw new Error("Failed");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("setted Error");

          setSignupError(err);
        });
    };
    (async () => {
      if (isLogin) {
        const response = await dbconnect(
          "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDXTW7owM4V9xy6RuUz8fI4nRKPcX-a2SU"
        );
        await response.then(dispatch(sliceActions.login(response.idToken)));
      } else {
        const response = await dbconnect(
          "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyDXTW7owM4V9xy6RuUz8fI4nRKPcX-a2SU"
        );
      }
    })();
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to return a result in `dbconnect` method. Try with the following code:

```js
const dbconnect = async (URL) => {
  return await fetch(URL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      returnSecureToken: false,
    }),
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json();
    else throw new Error("Failed");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("setted Error");

    setSignupError(err);

    return null;
  });
};
```

And other way:

```js
const dbconnect = async (URL) => {
  try {
    return await fetch(URL, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        returnSecureToken: false,
      }),
    }).then((result) => result.json());
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("setted Error");

    setSignupError(error);

    return null;
  }
};
```

I think you just forget the return.

Also the following lines:

```
if (isLogin) {
  const response = await dbconnect("your-url");
  await response.then(dispatch(sliceActions.login(response.idToken)));
} else {
  const response = await dbconnect("your-url");
}
```

`response` already has the result of the request so, you do not need to use the `.then` to send the dispatch so, I think you can use the following code.

```
if (isLogin) {
  const response = await dbconnect("your-url");

  await dispatch(sliceActions.login(response.idToken));
} else {
  const response = await dbconnect("your-url");
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Your "other way" worked perfectly, but the first ,method still not worked and the response getting undefined, Could you please let me know, what might be the cause of this?

Comment: complete code @ https://github.com/pranavmappoli/test

Comment: In the file `src/components/Auth/AuthForm.js`
```js
.then((res) => {
  // if (res.ok) console.log("ok"); // bad
  if (res.ok) {
    return res.json();
  };
  else throw new Error("Failed");
})

Answer (score 2):

`dbConnect` is marked as `async` so it returns a promise. It asynchronously calls `fetch` (without `await`ing it), then gets to the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement so it resolves the promise as `undefined`.

Rewrite your call to `fetch` to use `await` and `try/catch` instead of `.then` and `.catch`. Return the final result.

Comment: .then catch is not proper way to check?